# How to place two html elements that are full screen size on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack two elements that are full screen size on top of each other in html/css. I have the following html code so far

```
  <div className="main">
    <div className="intro">
      <div className="intro__header">
        Hello, world!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="about">
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to have the "intro" section sit on top of the "about" section. (This will allow you to scroll back and fourth between sections) Both the "intro" and "about" sections will each take up the size of the full screen. For example, if the screen was 900px by 900px, both sections will be 900px by 900px that sit on top of each other.

So far I have the "intro" section take up 100% of the screen using the following css.

```
.intro {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

How would I get the "about" section to also take up 100% of the screen but sit below the "intro" section

```
---------------
| intro       |
|             |
|_____________|
---------------
| about       |
|             |
|_____________|
```

The output would be the above with the "intro" section being 100% of the screen when you visit the page. Then you can scroll down to the "about" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the attribute `class`, not `className`.

After that is fixed, all you need to do is set the height of the first div, and maybe the margin of the body, which might already be covered if you have some kind  of [css reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

`100vh` is a convenient value to use. You can use `100%`, but that is relative to the container, so you would have to set the height of `.main` or of the body. `100vh` simply means the height of the viewport:

```css
.intro {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="intro__header">
      Hello, world!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about">About section
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! that did the trick. sorry for the confusion with className. I am just starting to learn react and they use "className"

Comment: Yeah, in JavaScript the property is called `className`, probably because `class` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `class` instead of `className`. `className` is JSX syntax, not HTML.

As to keeping each div centered depending on the viewport: set the height of each `div` to be `100vh`. To demonstrate, I've added a border around each div.

In this case, the `height` is calculating to subtract the 5px top and 5px bottom border:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.intro {
  height: calc(100vh - 10px);
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.about {
  height: calc(100vh - 10px);
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    Intro
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can use `border-box` to prevent having to calculate the border size:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.intro {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    Intro
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use percentages to accomplish the same thing, but there are a few caveats to this approach. With percentages, it will be determined based off of the sizing of the parent element. In this case, I set the global selector `*` to have a height of 100%, so it will work the same way, but only because the parent element is 100% of the viewport (or `100vh`).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.intro {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    Intro
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

If you change the parent element from 100% to 50%, you can see why `vh` is a much better unit than a percentage:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

.intro {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about {
  height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    Intro
  </div>
  <div class="about">
    About
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tip: you can use `box-sizing: border-box`, so you don't have to do the math to correct the size.

Comment: Very true, I've edited that in, as well as demonstrated how this can be done using percentages if the parent element is 100% of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw` work quite well.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.full-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 20px;
}

.intro {
  background: orange;
}

.about {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="intro full-page">
      <h2>Hello, world!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="about full-page">
      <h2>About page</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your css file:

```
 .intro, .about{height: 100vh;}
```